# connect and withRouter issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I am using Redux and React for my project. I have some Routes in App.js. I also use the connect function in react-redux in my project. To prevent update blocking issue, I usually wrapped my component in this way

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)),
```

However, If I changed order of withRouter and connect it doesn't work:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(App))
```

I have console.log the props in App.js. It already receives location and history props. I am figuring out the theory behind why the order does matter ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could you refer to this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter, it clearly says that it doesn't work the other way around

Comment: Where does it say it? Could you please quote the relevant part inside your answer?

Comment: oh hi i thought it was mentioned in the doc itself but looking at it now there doesn't seem to be one, maybe i was mistaken

Comment: Maybe it did mention it at some point, but it possibly changed since!

Answer (score 64):

You can use it with the method `compose` from redux library.

```
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(App);
```

Comment: What would the value of mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps be in this case? At App level, how should we define these two? Aren't these two specific to each component(to get those props from redux that this component is interested in)?

Comment: ```import {compose} from "redux";  //Code  

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(App);```

Comment: I did that but now I got `JSX element type 'App' does not have any construct or call signatures.  TS2604`

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in two ways,

**Proper Way:**

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToAction)(App));
```

with this, you will able to get withRouter props like history, match etc.. in mapStateToProps.

**2nd way:**

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToAction)(withRouter(App));
```

using this, you won't be able to get the withRouter props

Comment: This is working perfectly. In my react app v17.... react-router-dom 5 and redux latest.

Answer (score 6):

If someone still has the issue then plz follow this one

```js
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(Login);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowTheLocationWithRouter);
```

Comment: this will not work, becasue i got an  error   which react  raised that SetState function in the Login page(or the component which you will wrap)  will be a having a bad state,

Answer (score 0):

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(FacilitiesDropdown))
```

This solved my issue of using both connect and withRouter together