# How do I use withRouter in a react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am working on a login page and I have connected my login to redux. I followed this way below to connect it :

```
function mapState(state) {
    const { loggingIn, user } = state.authentication;
    const { alert } = state;
    return { loggingIn, alert, user };
}

const actionCreators = {
    login: userActions.login,
    logout: userActions.logout,
    clearAlerts: alertActions.clear
};

const connectedLoginPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(Login);
export { connectedLoginPage as Login };
```

Now, I want to use withRouter along with connect so how can I achieve this as it shows an error whenever I do it this way :

```
function mapState(state) {
    const { loggingIn, user } = state.authentication;
    const { alert } = state;
    return { loggingIn, alert, user };
}

const actionCreators = {
    login: userActions.login,
    logout: userActions.logout,
    clearAlerts: alertActions.clear
};

const connectedLoginPage = withRouter(connect(mapState, actionCreators)(Login));
export { connectedLoginPage as Login };
```

and here is a screenshot of the error I get :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this:  connect(mapState, actionCreators)((withRouter(Login))

Comment: @Saif can you add error message please?

Comment: @Rostyslav I have updated the post with a screenshot of the error. I wish I could get some help.

Comment: @Dani Would you pls check again. I followed your way and it shows the same error.

Comment: checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247082/connect-and-withrouter-issue